# How to Interpret EF Core Migration Timestamps

Tags: entity-framework

I've just completed an EF Core 2.1 migration and I get:

> 20180827153731_InitialCreate

The DOM/MO/YR is clear.

What about the rest of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what time was it when the file was created? –
> [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2416958/stefan)

yyyy mm dd hh mm ss

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it must be Universal Time; but, it'd be nice if it was formed using your Local Time Zone.

Comment: Local time, not so much.  Everything seems to be global-oriented nowadays.  Dispersed teams in multiple time zones creating updates to the same classes, generating migrations with "local" timestamps ... brrrr  I am reluctantly using UTC datetimes more and more.